# Как вывести из базы голый текст?

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести из базы голый текст, чтобы средствами php он красиво разделялся на абзацы. Плюс все картинки из текста автоматом центрировались

Comment: Такие вещи прописываются в css. А с "голым" текстом, если вы имели в виду, что он не размечен html-тегами, сделать что-либо крайне сложно. Разве что, средствами php разделять по определенному кол-ву предложений и всё равно придется оборачивать в теги.

Comment: а какой командой омерить предложенияиликол восимволов?
плюс найти переносы строксредствами php ?

Comment: я конечно извиняюсь за оффтоп, но у вас что за пользование клавиатуры дерут деньги или что? или ты трафик пробелами экономишь?

Comment: да так получается. сам только заметил. насчет траффика в точку

Answer (score 1):

так храните в базе текст с тегами, точнее перед записью в базу пропустите его через htmlentities, а при вытаскивании с базы пропускайте через html_entity_decode и все будет красиво

Comment: о. спасибо.будупробовать. спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 0):

в базу в html c необходимыми css классами и в принципе все, на выходе подключить необходимый css и будет вам счастье

Comment: ок спасибо цсс не подходиттк текст совсембезвсего

Comment: тогда смотрите в сторону тега <pre> - частично может помочь

Answer (score 0):

> чтобы средствами php он красиво
> разделялся на абзацы

По идее функция [nl2br](http://www.php.su/functions/?nl2br) должна красиво это сделать!

> Плюс все картинки из текста автоматом
> центрировались

```
img { display:block; margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: автор выше откомментировал, что применение css не подходит